# Generating output files using a nested for loop in Python, and getting invalid syntax error?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, syntax-error, nested-loops

I'm trying to generate some files which will have data from a for loop, and for now, I'm generating 20 files with the for loop of the following structure:

```
for t in range(1, 20, 1):
    file = open("data_" + str(t) + ".txt", "w+")
    for E in range(1, 20, 1): 
        stringData = str(t * E)          
        file = open("data_" + str(t) ".txt", "a")
        file.write(stringData + '\n')
        file.close()
```

However, I get the following syntax error:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-0fa0e5a273c1>", line 52
    file = open("data_" + str(t) ".txt", "a")
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know what the specific error is? I thought this was occurring because I was missing a parenthesis somewhere but I am not so sure. I'm new to Python so any assistance would mean a lot! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Compare your two open calls: the first does `str(t) + ".txt"`, and the second does `str(t) ".txt"`.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `+` sign. This is one reason that string formatting operations are better: fewer places to forget a character. The file name *template* is a single string, with the parameters following it, rather than trying to alternate fixed and variable pieces in a long expression.

```
open("data_%d.txt" % t, "w+")  # Pretty much every version of Python to date
```

or

```
open("data_{}.txt".format(t), "w+")  # Python 2.6 or later
```

Python 3.7 introduced a hybrid approach, *f-string literals*, which combine
executable expressions directly in the string literal (similar to string interpolation available in shell and Perl).

```
open(f"data_{t}.txt", "w+")  # Python 3.7 or later
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding strings.

```
file = open("data_" + str(t)+".txt", "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a + sign over there it should be

```
file = open("data_" + str(t)+".txt", "a")
```

Comment: Wow...thank you all. I can't believe I missed such a simple error.